# Intel Quick Sync Video codec

Tags: software-recommendation, video, intel, video-player, alternative

I'm looking for Intel Quick Sync Video codec and / or video encoding software that also can take benfit of Intel QSV.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about, but seems like Intel Quick Sync Video is not supported yet in Linux.

[Wikipedia: "Intel Quick Sync Video" Linux section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Quick_Sync_Video#Linux)

> Quick Sync is not currently supported on Linux. At the moment Intel
>   does not have any plan for implementing support although it has
>   been considered previously. On the other hand, an open source
>   programming manual was released in May 2012 which lets third
>   parties make use of the underlying functions instead.

And some forums:

- [Intel forum: "Linux support for the SDK"](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/311823)
- [VLC forum: "Howto Enable Intel Quick Sync H.264 GPU Encoding ?"](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=113579&hilit=qsv) (at 
  the end of this topic)

Comment: In fact, if you open the references at the Wiki and some Google searches, all the references are for Windows.

Comment: So it means,we need to wait a long time ?
Thankyou By The Way

Comment: Any update 3 years later?

Comment: @Enigma  Yes.  See the wikipedia article.